# How to set action as error for all stylecop rules

Tags: c#, stylecop

We are using StyleCop Analyzers in a C# project. (https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers)
The problem is how to set all action to "Error" instead of "Warning" about both rules code analysis(CAXXXX) and style analysis(SAXXXX).  Obviously I could list all rules like:

```
<Rule Id="CAXXXX" Action="Error" />
<Rule Id="SAXXXX" Action="Error" />
```

But that is inconvenient. Is there any other way to set it ?

The project used stylecop and set propertyGroup:

```
<StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>false</StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>
```

to set action as error. But that does not work in the new tool, stylecop analyzers.

Answer (score 10):

A quicker way to do this is:

On Analyzers, click Active Ruleset:

[image]

Giving something akin to:

[image]

Select them all:

[image]

Then click on any "Warning" and select "Error":

[image]

Then they are all set to "Error":

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To set all code analysis rules to have an Error action by default, the following can be added to a property group in the .csproj file:

```
<TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
```

This worked for both Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers and StyleCop.Analyzers packages added to a .NET Core 2.1 project.

Comment: This flag will treat all warnings and errors, not only for Stylecop and FxCop.